Charge besides conductor
This is a curiosity
What would be net charge induced on a (say spherical) conductor when a positive charge is placed besides it.
What I think is that a negative charge will be induced on surface near to charge
and a positive charge on other side.
However this will cause a field through a conductor which shall cause redistribution of charges such that net field is zero.
Still how in what manner  the charges be distributed and what will be the net charge?

Where would a net charge on the sphere come from?

I don't have time to write out the full answer, but see Example 3.2 in Griffith's E&M $4^\mathrm{th}$ or $5^\mathrm{th}$ edition. It gives $V(\mathbf{r})$, which can be used to find the surface charge. I believe your intuition is correct, and the net charge on the sphere will be whatever its original net charge was (which wasn't specified).

The positive charge produces an electric field which if nothing happened on the adjacent conductor would pass through the conductor.
However the induced charges on the conductor also produce an electric field.
The distribution of induced charges is such as to produce an electric field which at all points within the conductor is equal in magnitude and opposite in direction to the field produced by the positive charge.
The result is that there is no electric field within the conductor.
The derivation of the surface charge density on a spherical charge is published in many textbooks and online, eg A Point Charge and a Conducting Sphere and The method of images with a point charge and a grounded sphere.

If a positive charge is near (but not touching) the sphere it will not create a net charge on the sphere. It will only redistribute the existing charge on the sphere so that the negative charge (of the mobile electrons) moves towards the positive charge. This creates an electric field in the sphere equal and opposite to the field produced by the positive charge, for a net electric field of zero in the sphere.
Hope this helps.

Suppose the sphere has radius $R$ and we have a point charge $+q$ at distance $D$ from the sphere's center. Then the Induced charge distribution on the sphere's surface will give exactly the same field (and potential) as a set of two charges inside the sphere:

An image charge $q_{\hspace{1pt}\text{im}}=-\frac{R}{D}\,q$ at distance $d=\frac{R^{\large 2}}{D}$ from the center, in the same direction as the point charge $+q$.
A center charge $q_{\hspace{1pt}\text{cen}}=-q_{\hspace{1pt}\text{im}}=\frac{R}{D}\,q$.

So the total charge on the sphere is $0$. If the sphere is grounded then the center charge simply is not present (but you need to assume that an infinitely thin wire is used for the grounding, to avoid influence of the  wire on the field). For more details see e.g. [image_charges].
If you compute the field for these three point charges together (or only two for a grounded sphere) you will see that it is exactly normal to the surface, as it should be for the correct solution. You can then also find the surface charge density $\sigma$, which is proportional to the $E$-field at the surface by $\sigma=\varepsilon_0 E_\text{surf}$.
For the grounded sphere there will be negative surface charge everywhere on the sphere (with inward pointing $E$-field just outside the surface). For the floating sphere, the situation will be as you describe: near the point charge $+q$ there is negative surface charge, and positive charge on the opposite side. In fact there is positive charge on more than half of the sphere and consequently it is more spread out. See drawing below, where the field outside the sphere can be described by using either the red and blue surface charges, or the two black point charges inside the sphere, both choices describe the same external field:
$\qquad$ 
